# Delete values of array two that are in array one in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a very simple PHP question.

Imagine i have two array :

```
[array1] {
[0] => zero
[1] => one
[2] => two
[3] => three 
}
```

and

```
[array2] {
[0] => zero
[1] => test1
[2] => test2
[3] => three 
}
```

I want to delete every value from the second array that is in the first one.

For example, from that two arrays at top, I want to have this below array ::

```
[array2] {
[0] => test1
[1] => test2
}
```

How can we do it in PHP ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @showdev this is **Not** duplicate ! just read quesion with examples again u will under stand.

Comment: They are both duplicates. All of these answer your question. Please explain how they are unsatisfactory or edit your question to help clarify.

Comment: @showdev You are right, i am sorry :X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$array2 = array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

**Edit:** Here is an example:

```
$array1 = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three');
$array2 = array('zero', 'test1', 'test2', 'three');

$array2 = array_diff($array2, $array1);
print_r($array2);
```

Comment: Demo: http://codepad.org/CuOGoeXX

Comment: This is not the thing i need ! as @JaredFarrish showed !

Comment: @Cab I tested the code before I posted it. Added the test code to my answer. Can you please explain what is not working as expected?

Comment: @Cab - It does exactly what you describe.